# Why am I seeing a Big Sur Beta 11.3 update available even though I am not enrolled in the Beta Program?

Tags: software-update, big-sur

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) model and recently used migration assistant to transfer files from a Macbook Pro Mid-2014 model running Catalina. Previously, I had enrolled in the beta program on the Mid-2014 model, but unenrolled it. On my M1 Macbook Pro, I am seeing the Big Sur Beta 3 update even though the bottom left hand corner doesn't say anything about me being enrolled in a beta program. Furthermore, I cannot find any profiles in System Preferences for it. I have a screen shot below. Does anyone know why this is showing instead of 11.2.3?

[image]